# How can we jitter points in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a `data` as below:

```
data<-data.frame(ID=c("Study1","Study2","Study3", 
                      "Study1","Study2","Study3"),
                 avg=c(2,3,3.5,
                        2.5, 3.3, 4.0),
                 lower = c(1.8, 2.7, 3.15, 2.25, 2.97, 3.6),
                 upper = c(2.2, 3.3, 3.85, 2.75, 3.63, 4.4),
                 gender = c("m","m","m","f","f","f"))
```

The graph I want to plot is to visualize the average values of male and female within each studying group.

```
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = ID, y = avg, colour = ID)) +
  geom_point(size = 4, alpha = 0.6, position=position_jitter(width=0.5, seed = 50)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper),
               position = position_jitter(width = 0.5, seed = 50)) 
p
```

**Fig1**
[image]

I realized that the scatters of those points are very different. So, I decided to use `position_dodge` just to check the position of points.

```
pp <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = ID, y = avg, colour = ID)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))
pp
```

**Fig2**
[image]

This time, the points do not even move.

For fig3, I set `colour = ID` to show you how I imagine the scatter of points.

**Fig3**
[image]

In my mind, I would like to jitter points looks like `Fig3` (**points that represent sexes within each studying group are distributed evenly**).

Do you guys have any solutions for this case? Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Do you want to use `geom_jitter`?

Comment: ggplot has a jitters function: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_jitter.html

Comment: I was trying to use `geom_jitter` but the positions of points are very random.

Comment: @Quinten no Quinten :(. It didnot work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to tell ggplot to group your data by gender (in your `mapping = aes()` call). Otherwise it doesn't know to dodge them on that basis. By grouping correctly, you may not need to use `position_jitter()` you can just use `position_dodge()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(ID=c("Study1","Study2","Study3", 
                      "Study1","Study2","Study3"),
                 avg=c(2,3,3.5,
                       2.5, 3.3, 4.0),
                 lower = c(1.8, 2.7, 3.15, 2.25, 2.97, 3.6),
                 upper = c(2.2, 3.3, 3.85, 2.75, 3.63, 4.4),
                 gender = c("m","m","m","f","f","f")) 


p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = ID, y = avg, colour = ID, 
                           shape = gender, group = gender)) +
  geom_point(size = 4, alpha = 0.6, position=position_dodge(width=0.2)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper),
                 position = position_dodge(width = 0.2)) 
p
```

[image]

Incidentally you can use `geom_pointrange()` if you like rather than using `geom_point()` and `geom_linerange()` separately.

<sup>Created on 2022-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: oh yes, thank you so much @Kieran. That is true I forgot to group my gender variable

Comment: Grouping is always hard to remember—it's kind of the invisible aesthetic mapping, a little different from all the others. I think of it as telling ggplot when to put down and lift up the pen, so to speak, rather than what variable to draw as a shape or color or whatever.